# Why dont I get the interactive elements on my Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: filter, jupyter-notebook, interactive, ipywidgets

I would like to have interactive filters, according to the [documentation](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Using%20Interact.html#Using-Interact), this simple code should give me a filter and a slider but it just gives me a simple output.

Input:

```
from ipywidgets import interact
@interact(x=True, y=1.0)
    def g(x, y):
        return (x, y)
```

Output:

```
(True, 1.0)
```

I tried to run this on the terminal and restarted the Kernel but it didnt work either. [Source](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/1778).

```
jupyter nbextension enable --sys-prefix --py widgetsnbextension
```

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I had to run the command above in the environment where I am running the python in the terminal.